# Что за протокол QUIC? И куда уходят данные?

Tags: wireshark, протоколы

Решил разобрать wireshark и вот что заметил на своем андроиде на этот адрес - 77.75.144.18 по протоколу QUIC туда-сюда гуляют целая куча пакетов. Может кто пояснить что это?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC

Comment: IP-адрес принадлежит фейсбуку (сервер CDN в Украине), следовательно внутри QUIC скорее всего просто передаются картиночки по HTTP

Comment: @andreymal просто там за пол часа 100 тысяч пакетов ушло

Comment: @ДимаКоломиец с учётом максимального MTU (1500 байт) это всего лишь 143 мегабайта — примерно несколько десятков картинок в ленте новостей, ну или парочка видеороликов

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, теперь понятно почему так много.